# Testing if Enter-PSSession is successful

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there a way to test if Enter-PSSession is successful or if Enable-Remoting is already true? I don't need to be able to get into the machine itself, just a way to find out the return code. Basically, just checking to see if remoting into a machine can be done or if the machine still needs remoting to be enabled.

Comment: See if New-PSSession returns a session object, or an error?

Answer (score 5):

[`Enter-PSSession`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707(v=wps.620).aspx) is exclusively for interactive use.

To test whether remoting is enabled, use [`New-PSSession`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849717(v=wps.620).aspx):

```
$testSession = New-PSSession -Computer $targetComputer
if(-not($testSession))
{
    Write-Warning "$targetComputer inaccessible!"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Great! $targetComputer is accessible!"
    Remove-PSSession $testSession
}
```

If successful, `New-PSSession` will return the new PSSession object - if it failed it won't return anything, and `$testSession` is `$null` (thus making `-not($testSession) -eq $true`)

Comment: Does not catch some cases, e.g., user cancels password prompt.

Comment: @FlorianWinter Agree, you cannot give feedback to the user based on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
 Test-WSMan computername
```

or with autentication:

```
 Test-WSMan myserver -Credential peter -Authentication Negotiate
```

and then check the return object.

If that works PSSession should also work.

Comment: Test-WSMan session succeeds in cases where New-PSSession would raise an error instead. The only clue for me is that the ProductVersion property shows the Windows version to be zero. `Test-WSMan HOSTNAME | Select -Expand ProductVersion` produces `OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0`.

Comment: Testing with `-Authentication Negotiate` will reveal **Kerberos** issues - such as duplicate registered SPNs (`setspn -x`). [**WinRM** uses **Kerberos** by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so you have to explicity request **Negotiate**. This was a very helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
function CanRemote {
    $session = New-PSSession $ComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($session -is [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession])
        {Write-Host "Remote test succeeded: $ComputerName."}
    else
        {Write-Host "Remote test failed: $ComputerName."}
}
```

Comment: Does not catch some cases, e.g., user cancels password prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Try block, then just add -ErrorAction Stop

```
Try{
   $session = New-PSSession $ComputerName -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
   We got error..
}
```